# Don't show previous statements (ng-show)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I don't want to display the previous text when it goes to the two authors (or more).

```
<span ng-show="stepsdata.authors[0]">
    {{authors[0].surname}} {{authors[1].surname}} ({{year}} 
    <span ng-hide="stepsdata.endPage">p. {{page}})</span>
    <span ng-show="stepsdata.endPage">pp. {{stepsdata.startpage}} - {{stepsdata.lastpage}})</span>

</span>
<span ng-show="stepsdata.authors[1]"> Recent research 
    ({{authors[0].surname}} and {{authors[1].surname}}, {{year}}) suggests that...
</span>
<span ng-show="stepsdata.authors[2]"> Recent research 
    ({{authors[0].surname}}, {{authors[1].surname}} and {{authors[2].surname}}, {{year}}) suggests that...
</span>
<span ng-show="stepsdata.authors[3]"> Recent research 
    ({{authors[0].surname}}, et al., ({{year}}) suggests that...
</span>
```

If I have only one author it works great.

If I have two authors it displays the text from `ng-show="stepsdata.authors[0]`" and `ng-show="stepsdata.authors[1]`" but I need it only to show the text from `ng-show="stepsdata.authors[1]`"

If I have three authors it displays the text from `ng-show="stepsdata.authors[0]`" and `ng-show="stepsdata.authors[1]`" and then from `ng-show="stepsdata.authors[2]`" but I need it only to show the text from n`g-show="stepsdata.authors[2]`"

It happens also with the further cases.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `length` property of the array:

```
<span ng-show="stepsdata.authors.length == 1">
    {{authors[0].surname}} {{authors[1].surname}} ({{year}} 
    <span ng-hide="stepsdata.endPage">p. {{page}})</span>
    <span ng-show="stepsdata.endPage">pp. {{stepsdata.startpage}} - {{stepsdata.lastpage}})</span>

</span>
<span ng-show="stepsdata.authors.length == 2"> Recent research 
    ({{authors[0].surname}} and {{authors[1].surname}}, {{year}}) suggests that...
</span>
<span ng-show="stepsdata.authors.length == 3"> Recent research 
    ({{authors[0].surname}}, {{authors[1].surname}} and {{authors[2].surname}}, {{year}}) suggests that...
</span>
<span ng-show="stepsdata.authors.length == 4"> Recent research 
    ({{authors[0].surname}}, et al., ({{year}}) suggests that...
</span>
```